# How to speed up update of html elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use the following code currently -

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
  // read list of items from the table
  ...
  // getting data the DB
  var connectionstring="Data Source=datasource;Initial Catalog=catalog;User 
  ID=userid;Password=pass;Provider=SQLOLEDB";

  connection.Open(connectionstring);
  var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

  rs.Open("select top 10 from db where id in myitems_list")

... 
// display the result
for (currentRow = 1; currentRow < myitems_list.length + 1; currentRow++) { 
    rs.MoveFirst;
    while(!rs.eof)
        if (jQuery(jQuery(".mytable")[1].rows[currentRow].cells[0]).text().trim()==rs.fields(0)) {
jQuery(jQuery(".mytable")[1].rows[currentRow].cells[1]).html(rs.fields(1));
        ...
    }
});
```

Here I do the following:

1. read list of items (there ids) from the first column of the table
2. for each item found in the table get the data from the database
3. update the table with the data received from the database (initial order of the items should be unchanged)

It takes a few minutes to update the table.
What can I do to speed process of table update?
Or, probably, I should move it to separate thread?

Comment: what is 'rs' ? why do you have this statement while(!rs.eof)?

Comment: Assuming the bottleneck isn't slow AJAX, it might be worth using something like React.js for this as the virtual DOM it uses will be a lot faster than updating it with jQuery.

Comment: @karthick, I've updated the code in the question. But it is not important here.

Comment: For each row in the table you loop through the whole recordset looking for a match?  Yes, that sounds expensive and slow.

Comment: Sounds like your algorithm can be improved before looking for bottlenecks in Javascript. Could also try storing `jQuery(".mytable")[1].rows` outside of the loop so it's not performing the DOM traversal and lookup every single iteration.

Comment: @MatthewDaly, this is Confluence page, so I can not user React here.

Comment: @James, any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Did you checked what is taking time, your db query or the DOM manipulation. How many records are you expecting?

Comment: @PSK, DOM manipulation takes a lot of time. There are ~30 records.

Comment: @LA 1.data is from ajax or not? 2 can you provide json and html result? please this is really important to give you the best answer. because i need to fix your jquery checking too

Comment: @plonknimbuzz, no, I read the data from the SQL database. I've updated the question with more details.

Comment: @LA_ can we chat for a while? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165114/table #15min no response i will leave the chat

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure what this pattern is called, but you have two *sorted* datasets and you want to update one from the other efficiently.  You can use an algorithm which loops through each list once.

Sort both lists the same way, and create a counter variable for each list.
Compare the *ith* element of a1 with the *jth* element of a2.  If equal, update a1 from a2 and increment i and j.  If less than, increment i.  Otherwise increment j.

```
var a1 = [sorted array];
var a2 = [similarly sorted array];

var i=0, j=0;

while (i < a1.length && j < a2.length) {
  if (a1[i] == a2[j]) {
    // update a1[i]
    i++;
    j++;
  } else if (a1[i] < a2[j]) {
    i++;
  } else {
    j++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, James. I am not sure how to sort the recordset (this it the result of SQL database query) and I can not change the sorting order of the table values (`jQuery(".mytable")[1]`) - the order is important here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the loop over `rs` object.

When I changed the code to

```
// display the result
rs.MoveFirst;
while(!rs.eof) {
    for (currentRow = 1; currentRow < myitems_list.length + 1; currentRow++) { 
        if (jQuery(jQuery(".mytable")[1].rows[currentRow].cells[0]).text().trim()==rs.fields(0)) {
jQuery(jQuery(".mytable")[1].rows[currentRow].cells[1]).html(rs.fields(1));
        ...
        break;
    }
});
```

it started to work fast.

Answer (score 0):

A technique that doesn’t require sorting.  Build a hashtable from your existing content that maps the id to the html element, then use the hashtable.

```
var ht = {};

for (currentRow = 1; currentRow < myitems_list.length + 1; currentRow++) {
        ht[jQuery(".mytable")[1].rows[currentRow].cells[0]).text().trim()] = jQuery(".mytable")[1].rows[currentRow].cells[1];
    }

rs.MoveFirst;
while(!rs.eof) {
  if(ht[rs.fields(0)]) {
    jQuery(ht[rs.fields(0)]).html(rs.fields(1));
  }
  rs.MoveNext();
}
```